# URL redirection when website is down for maintenance

Tags: url, redirect

I have some websites to redirect to another URL as they are down for maintenance. It is tiresome doing it manually on IIS. I wanted to know if there is a specific command line or script that i can use to get the work done quicker. I have IIS 6 and windows server 2003. Thanks in advance for your help.

Answer (score 0):

If you have an ASP.NET web application site, and you place a text file named "app_offline.htm" in the root of the site, all requests to that website will redirect to that app_offline.htm file.  See [this blog post](http://weblogs.asp.net/pleloup/archive/2008/09/22/taking-an-asp-net-site-offline-with-a-message.aspx) for details.

Comment: Thanks Pino. Will definely consider this one.

Comment: Well, in this case you should formally approve the answer by adding a green check to it.  This is the way Stackoverflow works.